# Jquery toggle .. fixing alighnment

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello people i have this script

```
<a class="clickMe" toggle="first">Text 1</a>
</br>
<div id="first" class="text"> - This text will be toggled</div>

<a class="clickMe" toggle="second">Text 2</a>
</br>
<div id="second" class="text"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>
```

and the jquery

```
 $('a.clickMe').click(function () {
   id = $(this).attr('toggle');
   $('.text').not('#' + id).hide();
   $('#' + id).show();
 });
```

above code works fine by toggling `This text will be toggled` or `This text will be toggled 2` when we click on `Text 1` or `Text 2` is clicked, please check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LTYa2/53/)

but now what i trying to do is to have fixed position/alignment for the toggled text,right now it is toggled below Text 1 or Text 2 ,BUT I NEED TO PUT THIS ON RIGHT HAND SIDE SO THAT WHEN EVER ANYONE OF THE TEXT1 OR TEXT2 IS CLICKED TOGGLED STATEMENT SHOULD BE SHOWN ON THE SAME PLACE(RIGHT SIDE NOT BELOW) ...PLEASE HELP ME TO FIX THIS....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try this by using jQuery's `.text()` feature:

> http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/pe8xV/2/

Comment: hello flame ,thanks for trying,its exactly what iam looking for but in your code its hard coded ....  `$('#' + id).text('- This text will be toggled '+id);' toggled statements could be different  for different scenarios so i can not hard code.....

Comment: Hello flame ...thanks alot for showing interest in answering this question..well i can not use the code which is hard coded,bcos i am using foreach loop ,and iam not sure which id will be next and iam also using blocks/<tds> in place of statements,blocks and <tds> can not be hard coded...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a non-block element like `span` and `toggle` method.

```
<a class="clickMe">Text 1</a>
<span class="text"> - This text will be toggled</span>
<br/>
<a class="clickMe">Text 2</a>
<span class="text"> - This text will be toggled 2</span>
```

```
$('a.clickMe').click(function () {
   $(this).next().toggle()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LTYa2/66/

Comment: hello undefined thanks for giving a try..well i need both "This text will be toggled 2" and "This text will be toggled" come at the same place. and i can not use span bcos the functionality changes , check it 'This text will be toggled' and 'This text will be toggled 2' both are displayed when 'text 1' is clicked..

Comment: @Google Hi, what you are describing differs from your question, `both are displayed when 'text 1' is clicked`? So why you have 2 anchor links? If you don't want to use span elements you can style your divs as inline-block.

Comment: Hello undefined ,it was giving a different result may be bcos u had used different jquery in fiddle.. well its working fine , i think i can use span it self, and let you know the resuld...

Comment: hello undefined , i need both "This text will be toggled " and "This text will be toggled 2" to come at the same place –

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/LTYa2/68/)** is the corrected working Live Demo.

Comment: hello blasteralfred thanks for attempting to answer..iam checking your code too.

Comment: hello blasteralfred i need both "This text will be toggled " and "This text will be toggled 2" to come at the same place